# A memory leak in simpleftp

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I use [simpleFTP](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/Read_Me_About_SimpleFTPSample_txt.html) to request document information. I detect memory-leak with instrument as below:

[image]

And in the call tree I find out where is the memory leak happened:

[image]

The method "_parseListData" as below:

```
- (void)_parseListData
{
    NSMutableArray *    newEntries;
    NSUInteger          offset;

    // We accumulate the new entries into an array to avoid a) adding items to the 
    // table one-by-one, and b) repeatedly shuffling the listData buffer around.

    newEntries = [NSMutableArray array];
    assert(newEntries != nil);

    offset = 0;
    do {
        CFIndex         bytesConsumed;
        CFDictionaryRef thisEntry;

        thisEntry = NULL;

        assert(offset <= self.listData.length);
        bytesConsumed = CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing(NULL, &((const uint8_t *) self.listData.bytes) [offset], self.listData.length - offset, &thisEntry);
        if (bytesConsumed > 0) {
........
}
```

I don't know how to fix this problem.

The method "`CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing`" is a system method and it create `__NSDate` (*look at the second pic*).

This is where the memory-leak happen.

Answer (score 0):

The `CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing` function returns a `CFDictionary` into the `thisEntry` variable, which presumably contains the `NSDate` objects.

The code should call `CFRelease` on `thisEntry` once it is finished with it:

```
// once we're done with thisEntry
if (thisEntry) {
    CFRelease(thisEntry);
}
```

Comment: This code has been included in this function as : if (thisEntry != NULL) {
            CFRelease(thisEntry);
        } I just bypass it

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but useful solution. You can find the answer here [BlackRaccoon ftp client](https://github.com/lloydsargent/BlackRaccoon/blob/master/BlackRaccoon/BlackRaccoon/BRRequestListDirectory.m).
According to the creator the CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing method retains twice the NSDate, to override the issue add the next code, be aware of the comments here:
[FAQ section](https://github.com/lloydsargent/BlackRaccoon/wiki)
"Actually, in WhiteRaccoon, if you list a directory you will leak NSDate's. The function CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing in Apple's SDK has a leak in it. I've attempted to "patch" this, however it isn't guaranteed to work. For OS 5.1 it does work."

```
            ........
            if (parsedBytes > 0)
            {
                if (listingEntity != NULL)
                {
                    //----- July 10, 2012: CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing had a bug that had the date over retained
                    //----- in order to fix this, we release it once. However, just as a precaution, we check to see what
                    //----- the retain count might be (this isn't guaranteed to work).
                    id date = [(__bridge NSDictionary *) listingEntity objectForKey: (id) kCFFTPResourceModDate];
                    if (CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef) date) >= 2)
                        CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef) date);
```

this works for me

Comment: (sigh) Yes, this is a nasty, nasty, hack that I wrote in order to get around the leak. It appears to work for iOS 5 and iOS 6. I can't say if it does for iOS 7.